# Which network is accessed is connected when a computer is connected to a LAN & WiFi network?

Tags: networking

When a computer is connected a LAN and Wifi network, then which network will the device access?

Comment: The one which has the lowest metric in the routing table.

Comment: Hey why -2(i had 6 now its 4), i had this doubt when i was using my laptop with both connected?

Comment: So I've always wondered how I could tell my computer which one to use. I guess it's way easier than I thought. Simply mess with the `route` command (on Windows at least) and set the `metric` field to what I want. Wonderful!

Answer (score 0):

The commenter above is correct. Typically you want to prioritize hardwired connections over wireless connections ( hardwired connections are normally faster and more reliable ).  Some distros will do this for you I believe, and some of that depends on which network manager you use, if any at all.  I'm not sure which the kernel prioritizes if you have a wifi connection with a metric of 0 and an ethernet connection with a metric of 0, that's a pretty good question.